# How to change header image size in custom themes

Tags: templates, custom-header

I'm using WP 3.5 for a CMS for one of our clients. I need to have a bigger header image than 940 × 250 pixels, so I changed width and height parameters, but when I try to upload a new image, it still asks me to crop it. What am I doing wrong?

```
    $settings = array(
    'width'                  => 1700,
    'height'                 => 300,
    'flex-height'            => true,
    'flex-width'             => true,
    'header-text'            => false,
    'uploads'                => true,
);
add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $settings );
```

Comment: What theme are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Twenty Eleven, just add this to your functions.php file and you should be good to go:

```
remove_filter( 'HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH', 'twentyeleven_header_image_width' );
remove_filter( 'HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT', 'twentyeleven_header_image_height' );
define( 'HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH', apply_filters( 'child_header_image_width', 1700) );
define( 'HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT', apply_filters( 'child_header_image_height', 300) );
```